# Why doesn't the notification mark itself as read automatically after I read the comment it's about?

Tags: bug, comments, notifications

1. Someone left a comment on my question.
2. Without looking at the notification, I opened the question and replied.
3. Then I reloaded the page. I expected no notifications to show up about the comment which I already processed.
4. Yet the notification about the comment was still active and unread.

That's unintuitive and annoying at best.

Comment: It's never bothered me (and it may well be that there are compelling architectural reasons for it), but I suppose technically you're right

Comment: The inbox doesn't know that. The message in the inbox is completely denormalized. It's *just* a block of text and all the system knows is "I need to show this user this block of text." AFAIK notifications aren't even associated with a post ID.

Comment: Plus just because you scroll past a comment doesn't mean you realised it was there and read it. I'd much rather be notified for every comment than miss some because the system thinks I've probably read them.

Comment: @OGHaza I _replied_ to the comment, like I did to yours now, and pinged you. I definitely read it.